# cant move ul.width to width:0px

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="filter">
  <ul>
    <span class="filter-icon text-gray-lightest">  <!--    svg-inline--fa   -->
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><polyline points="15 6 9 12 15 18"></polyline></svg>
    </span>
    <li data-filter="f0">Alle</li>
    <li data-filter="f1">Verw/Fin</li>
    <li data-filter="f2">MaPa</li>
    <li data-filter="f3">Presse</li>
    <li data-filter="f4">Programme</li>
    <li data-filter="f5">Inland</li>
    <li data-filter="f6">Controlling</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
.filter {
    margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
  width: 40%;
  background-color:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.filter ul {
 padding-left:8px;
}

.filter-icon {
display: inline-block;
fill: currentColor;
stroke: currentColor;
vertical-align: middle;
transition: transform .5s;
height:16px; width:16px;
}

.filter-icon:hover {
fill: var(--orange);
stroke: #000;
 transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.filter ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px;
  position:relative;
}

.filter:hover {
  width:50px;
}
```

I would like to change the width of the div.filter with javascript to 0px.
for better test i made here a filter:hover to 50px.
Please see [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hamburger123456/pen/YzxrPMy)

My Problem is, that the filter-box gets higher. But I would like that the content of the filter-box disapear (by overflow:hidden).
How to achieve this?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't place the `span` inside `ul` in the way you have done. It could be either out of the `ul` or inside a `li`.

Comment: thx. you can delete the span. its just for layout. the result is the same

Comment: I don't understand: `div.filter { width: 0px }` isn't visible on the page, while the `div.filter:hover` isn't hoverable in theory.

Answer (score -1):

```
let filter = document.getElementsByClassName("filter")[0];
filter.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){filter.style.display = "none"});
filter.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){filter.style.display = "block"});
```

Comment: It's better to add `display: none` than to shrink the filter.

Comment: Yeah you are right.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry. I Do not have problems with javascript. My problem is css. That I do not get shrink the div.container to 0.